# Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraWinGrid.ActiveRowScrollRegion.ScrollRowIntoView() is very slow

Tags: infragistics, vertical-scrolling, ultrawingrid

I am using Infragistics UltraWinGrid from NetAdvantage for Windows Forms v10.3 . If there are a lot of rows and I execute UltraWinGrid.ActiveRowScrollRegion.ScrollRowIntoView(), then it scrolls really slow. Is there a way of how to speed up the scrolling? Perhaps there is a way to set the scroll speed?

I've tried to post this question on Infragistics forums, but the "new post" button is disabled for WinForms section. Probably it is enabled only for subscribed users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now I am using  UltraWinGrid.ActiveRowScrollRegion.ScrollPosition = UltraWinGrid.Rows.IndexOf(row) which scrolls instantly, but that is not very user-friendly because it is hard for the user to notice what is going on. I would prefer real scrolling.